# Can't connect to open wifi - Intel 7260

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, intel-wireless, iwlwifi

I'm unable to connect to my open wifi which is a mobile hotspot. I've been struggling with this problem for quite some time. I can connect to any
secured wifi just fine, but when trying to connect to my mobile hotspot I get:

```
(wifi) connection 'OpenGarden' requires no security.  No secrets needed.
(wifi) Ad-Hoc network creation took too long, failing activation
```

I get this same error no matter how many times I restart all devices. My wifi card is an Intel 7260. I'm currently running on Ubuntu 16.10 and I think I've troubleshot it down to the version of the drivers.

When booting up I get the following errors in `journalctl`:

```
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Unsupported splx structure
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-19.ucode failed with error -2
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-18.ucode failed with error -2
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-17.ucode failed with error -2
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 16.242414.0 op_mode iwlmvm
```

I had previously loaded up Ubuntu 15.04, and my wifi was able to connect just fine to the unsecured hotspot. The line I had in my log when starting up with that configuration was:

```
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Unsupported splx structure
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 25.15.12.0 op_mode iwlmvm
```

So, how do I load the old drivers in 16.10? Has anyone ever heard of an issue like this?

***EDIT***

Ok, here's a definite update!

I ran `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` and it reports a 7265:

```
Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 59)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:5110]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

Sorry for the previous incorrect information.

I've copied all of the various iwlwifi-7265D* drivers from newest to oldest and I'm still unable to connect to the mobile hotspot.

After trying to connect, this is the output from journalctl:

```
wpa_supplicant[1822]: wlp2s0: Trying to associate with SSID 'OpenGarden1
wpa_supplicant[1822]: Could not set interface wlp2s0 flags (UP): Device 
wpa_supplicant[1822]: nl80211: Failed to set interface into IBSS mode
wpa_supplicant[1822]: wlp2s0: Association request to the driver failed
NetworkManager[723]: <info>  [1479746689.7772] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> disconnected
wpa_supplicant[1822]: wlp2s0: Trying to associate with SSID 'OpenGarden1'
wpa_supplicant[1822]: wlp2s0: Association request to the driver failed
wpa_supplicant[1822]: wlp2s0: Trying to associate with SSID 'OpenGarden1'
wpa_supplicant[1822]: wlp2s0: Association request to the driver failed
wpa_supplicant[1822]: wlp2s0: Trying to associate with SSID 'OpenGarden1
wpa_supplicant[1822]: wlp2s0: Association request to the driver failed
wpa_supplicant[1822]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="OpenGarden1" auth_failues=1 duration=10 reason=CONN_FAILED
wpa_supplicant[1822]: wlp2s0: Trying to associate with SSID 'OpenGarden1
wpa_supplicant[1822]: wlp2s0: Association request to the driver failed
wpa_supplicant[1822]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="OpenGarden1" auth_failues=2 duration=20 reason=CONN_FAILED
wpa_supplicant[1822]: wlp2s0: Trying to associate with SSID 'OpenGarden1
wpa_supplicant[1822]: wlp2s0: Association request to the driver failed
wpa_supplicant[1822]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="OpenGarden1" auth_failues=3 duration=30 reason=CONN_FAILED
NetworkManager[723]: <warn>  [1479746714.6399] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) Ad-Hoc network creation took too long, failing
NetworkManager[723]: <info>  [1479746714.6400] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> failed (reason 'supplicant-timeout')
NetworkManager[723]: <info>  [1479746714.6404] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
NetworkManager[723]: <warn>  [1479746714.6410] device (wlp2s0): Activation: failed for connection 'Auto OpenGarden1'
NetworkManager[723]: <info>  [1479746714.6419] device (wlp2s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none')
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: In addition, can we get the model and make of your machine?

Comment: The make and model is ASUS  gl752vw

Comment: @chili555 Deleted answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I suggest you upgrade the firmware files:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.161_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

Reboot.

Second, we wonder why the mode gets set to Ad-Hoc. Is that the setting in your mobile hotspot or did you set Network Manager to use Ad-Hoc? That is incorrect to connect to any hotspot that offers an internet connection. Ad-Hoc is for a private computer-to-computer connection. Infrastructure or Client mode is for connecting to any wireless access point that offers an internet connection. Please clarify the origin of Ad-Hoc; if needed, I will further edit my question to add suggestions.

Comment: I am using the OpenGarden wifi tether app for Android. I'm unable to tell where the Ad-Hoc comes in to play. The settings are fairly basic. I can change the SSID, the channel, and the encryption. That's about it though.

Comment: If you select 'Edit Connections' in Network Manager, is WiFi set to Infrastructure?

Comment: I checked, and it's set to Ad-Hoc mode. Whenever I edit it to something else such as Client and then try to connect, it creates another connection with mode set to Ad-Hoc and fails.

Comment: Since you can connect with other wifi networks perfectly well, and since we see the jump to ad-hoc mode, I feel that the problem is with the OpenGarden app. A Google search for OpenGarden and ad-hoc yields several hits but no solution that I can see.